# C++ traits question for template specialization

Tags: c++, templates

I have two classes:

```cpp
class RowMatrix
{
public:
    double* getRowSlice ();
    double get (int row, int column);
    void set (int row, int column);
};

class ColumnMatrix
{
public:
    double* getColumnSlice ();
    double get (int row, int column);
    void set (int row, int column);
};
```

Now, for vector operations, getRowSlice () / getColumnSlice () can be much faster than using the more generic get / set operations.

```cpp
template<class MatrixOut, class MatrixIn>
copy (MatrixOut& out, const MatrixIn& in)
{
  if (in.isRowMatrix () && out.isRowMatrix ())
  {
    // row based copy
    int rows = in.getNumRows ();
    for (int y = 0; y < rows; ++y)
    {
       vectorCopy (out.getRowSlice (y), in.getRowSlice (y));
    }
  }
  else if (in.isRowMatrix () && out.isRowMatrix ())
  {
    // column based copy
  }
  else
  {
    genericCopy (out, in);
  }
}
```

The current issue is that compiler would generate errors that getRowSlice is missing in ColumnMatrix and getColumnSlice is missing in RowMatrix.

What is the approach to specialize the implementation?  One major issue here is that because I have quite a few different RowMatrix and ColumnMatrix implementations (and they do not inherit each other).  So, it is a bit tedious to create copy<RowMatrix1, RowMatrix1> for different combinations of RowMatrix implementations and copy<ColumnMatrix1, ColumnMatrix2> implementations.  And I do not want to create inheritances for these classes.  This is also just one of the algorithms that I would like to optimize.

I thought that using C++ traits could help, but I still run into the same error.

```cpp
template<bool a, bool b>
struct MatrixTraits
{
  static constexpr bool isRowMatrix () { return a; }
  static constexpr bool isColumnMatrix () { return b; }
};

class RowMatrix
{
public:
    typedef MatrixTraits<true, false>  Traits;

    const double* getRowSlice () const { return nullptr; }
    double* getRowSlice () { return nullptr; }
    void set (int row, int column, double value) { }
    double get (int row, int column) { return 0; }
};

class ColumnMatrix
{
public:
    typedef MatrixTraits<false, true>  Traits;

    const double* getColumnSlice () const { return nullptr; }
    double* getColumnSlice () { return nullptr; }
    void set (int row, int column, double value) { }
    double get (int row, int column) { return 0; }
};

template<class MatrixOut, class MatrixIn>
void
generalCopy (MatrixOut& out, const MatrixIn& in)
{
}

void
vectorCopy (double*, const double*)
{
}

template<class MatrixOut, class MatrixIn>
void
copy (MatrixOut& out, const MatrixIn& in)
{
    if (MatrixIn::Traits::isRowMatrix () && MatrixOut::Traits::isRowMatrix ())
    {
        vectorCopy (out.getRowSlice (), in.getRowSlice ());
    }
    else if (MatrixIn::Traits::isColumnMatrix () && MatrixOut::Traits::isColumnMatrix ())
    {
        vectorCopy (out.getColumnSlice (), in.getColumnSlice ());
    }
    else
    {
        generalCopy (out, in);
    }
}

int main ()
{
    RowMatrix   m1;
    RowMatrix   m2;

    copy (m1, m2);
    return 0;
}
```

I still ran into the same error that columnMatrix is missing getRowSlice ().

Here is the error message:

```
m.cpp:64:17:   required from here
m.cpp:51:25: error: ‘class RowMatrix’ has no member named ‘getColumnSlice’; did you mean ‘getRowSlice’?
   51 |         vectorCopy (out.getColumnSlice (), in.getColumnSlice ());
      |                     ~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
      |                     getRowSlice
m.cpp:51:47: error: ‘const class RowMatrix’ has no member named ‘getColumnSlice’; did you mean ‘getRowSlice’?
   51 |         vectorCopy (out.getColumnSlice (), in.getColumnSlice ());
      |                                            ~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
      |                                            getRowSlice
```

Can anyone help?  Thanks.

Edit: This version works.

```cpp
#include <cstdio>

template<bool a, bool b>
struct MatrixTraits
{
  static bool constexpr isRowMatrix () { return a; }
  static bool constexpr isColumnMatrix () { return b; }
};

class RowMatrix
{
public:
    typedef MatrixTraits<true, false>  Traits;

    const double* getRowSlice () const { return nullptr; }
    double* getRowSlice () { return nullptr; }
    void set (int row, int column, double value) { }
    double get (int row, int column) { return 0; }
};

class ColumnMatrix
{
public:
    typedef MatrixTraits<false, true>  Traits;

    const double* getColumnSlice () const { return nullptr; }
    double* getColumnSlice () { return nullptr; }
    void set (int row, int column, double value) { }
    double get (int row, int column) { return 0; }
};

template<class MatrixOut, class MatrixIn>
void
generalCopy (MatrixOut& out, const MatrixIn& in)
{
    printf ("%s: %d\n", __FUNCTION__, __LINE__);
}

void
vectorCopy (double*, const double*)
{
    printf ("%s\n", __FUNCTION__);
}

template<class MatrixOut, class MatrixIn, bool bothRowMatrix>
struct RowCopier
{
    static void
    copy (MatrixOut& out, const MatrixIn& in)
    {
        printf ("should not get here");
    }
};

template<class MatrixOut, class MatrixIn>
struct RowCopier<MatrixOut, MatrixIn, true>
{
    static void
    copy (MatrixOut& out, const MatrixIn& in)
    {
        printf ("%s: %d\n", __FUNCTION__, __LINE__);
        vectorCopy (out.getRowSlice (), in.getRowSlice ());
    }
};

template<class MatrixOut, class MatrixIn, bool bothColumnMatrix>
struct ColumnCopier
{
    static void
    copy (MatrixOut& out, const MatrixIn& in)
    {
        printf ("should not get here");
    }
};

template<class MatrixOut, class MatrixIn>
struct ColumnCopier<MatrixOut, MatrixIn, true>
{
    static void
    copy (MatrixOut& out, const MatrixIn& in)
    {
        printf ("%s: %d\n", __FUNCTION__, __LINE__);
        vectorCopy (out.getColumnSlice (), in.getColumnSlice ());
    }
};

template<class MatrixOut, class MatrixIn>
void
copy (MatrixOut& out, const MatrixIn& in)
{
    if (MatrixIn::Traits::isRowMatrix () && MatrixOut::Traits::isRowMatrix ())
    {
        RowCopier<MatrixOut, MatrixIn, MatrixIn::Traits::isRowMatrix () && MatrixOut::Traits::isRowMatrix ()>::copy (out, in);
    }
    else if (MatrixIn::Traits::isColumnMatrix () && MatrixOut::Traits::isColumnMatrix ())
    {
        ColumnCopier<MatrixOut, MatrixIn, MatrixIn::Traits::isColumnMatrix () && MatrixOut::Traits::isColumnMatrix ()>::copy (out, in);
    }
    else
    {
        generalCopy (out, in);
    }
}

int main ()
{
    RowMatrix   m1;
    RowMatrix   m2;

    copy (m1, m2);

    ColumnMatrix    m3;
    ColumnMatrix    m4;

    copy (m3, m4);

    copy (m1, m4);
    copy (m3, m2);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: *"The current issue is that..."* Don't explain the error, instead post the complete error into your question along with a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: *"I thought that using C++ traits could help, but I still run into the same error...."* Which error? Post the complete error.

Comment: In the end  of the day it is easier to just overload your function and forget about templates and specialisations and traits and all that stuff.

Comment: You're in C++14, in your copy function. You are using "simple" if, thus all branches are compiled, even if not used, thus you are compiling RowCopier even for non all row-matrices.
It's why you have to use one of the compile-time dispatch technics I propose in my answer (SFINAE or functor partial specialization, if your stuck to C++14).

Comment: Apparently I had a typo in there that prevented the partial specialization code to work.  Now it works pretty well.  I will explore / learn the enable_if thing to see it can makes it simpler.  Thanks for your help and examples.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, your snippet contained many errors, unrelated to the question of traits. This is a cleaned up example:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

template <bool a, bool b>
class MatrixTraits {
    // 1- adding missing public keyword
   public:
    static bool isRowMatrix() { return a; }
    static bool isColumnMatrix() { return b; }
};

class RowMatrix {
   public:
    typedef MatrixTraits<true, false> Traits;
};

class ColumnMatrix {
   public:
    typedef MatrixTraits<false, true> Traits;
};

// 2- just needed to compile the last case below
template <class MatrixOut, class MatrixIn>
void genericCopy(MatrixOut&, const MatrixIn&) {
    std::cout << "generic copy" << std::endl;
}

// 3- adding missing return type
template <class MatrixOut, class MatrixIn>
void copy(MatrixOut& out, const MatrixIn& in) {
    if (MatrixIn::Traits::isRowMatrix() && MatrixOut::Traits::isRowMatrix()) {
        // row based copy
        std::cout << "row based copy" << std::endl;
    } else if (MatrixIn::Traits::isColumnMatrix() &&
               MatrixOut::Traits::isColumnMatrix()) {
        std::cout << "column based copy" << std::endl;
    } else {
        genericCopy(out, in);
    }
}

int main() {
    RowMatrix Rin, Rout;
    ColumnMatrix Cin, Cout;
    copy(Rout, Rin);
    copy(Cout, Cin);
    return 0;
}
```

[Live Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/dKovfoTdd)

Yet as to the traits issue, here is a cleaner and more "vanilla" way to use them:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

// in general, a MatrixType is not a row matrix
template <typename MatrixType>
struct isRowMatrix : public std::false_type {};
// same for column matrix
template <typename MatrixType>
struct isColMatrix : public std::false_type {};

// declare your classes
class RowMatrix {};
class ColumnMatrix {};

// now you can specialize the trait

// A RowMatrix, is a row matrix
template <>
struct isRowMatrix<RowMatrix> : public std::true_type {};
// A ColumnMatrix, is a row matrix
template <>
struct isColMatrix<ColumnMatrix> : public std::true_type {};

// 2- just needed to compile the last case below
template <class MatrixOut, class MatrixIn>
void genericCopy(MatrixOut&, const MatrixIn&) {
    std::cout << "generic copy" << std::endl;
}

// wrapping copy into a struct in order to use partial specialization again
// generic case
template <class MatrixOut, class MatrixIn,
          bool BothCol =
              isColMatrix<MatrixOut>::value && isColMatrix<MatrixIn>::value,
          bool BothRows =
              isRowMatrix<MatrixOut>::value && isRowMatrix<MatrixIn>::value>
struct Copier {
    static void copy(MatrixOut& out, const MatrixIn& in) {
        genericCopy(out, in);
    }
};
// specialization for columns only
template <class MatrixOut, class MatrixIn>
struct Copier<MatrixOut, MatrixIn, true, false> {
    static void copy(MatrixOut& out, const MatrixIn& in) {
        std::cout << "column based copy" << std::endl;
    }
};
// specialization for rows only
template <class MatrixOut, class MatrixIn>
struct Copier<MatrixOut, MatrixIn, false, true> {
    static void copy(MatrixOut& out, const MatrixIn& in) {
        std::cout << "row based copy" << std::endl;
    }
};

// wrapping it into a function to keep it user friendly and get use of template
// argument deduction
template <class MatrixOut, class MatrixIn>
void copy(MatrixOut& out, const MatrixIn& in) {
    Copier<MatrixOut, MatrixIn>::copy(out, in);
}

int main() {
    RowMatrix Rin, Rout;
    ColumnMatrix Cin, Cout;
    copy(Rout, Rin);
    copy(Cout, Cin);
    return 0;
}
```

[Live Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/sErj4rMM9)

Basically:

1. declare your default case for the trait that should inherit from
   std::true_type or std::false_type (it's not mandatory but its
   considered as good practice)
2. declare your classes
3. specialize the trait(s) for these class
4. define the generic signature of your "function" and implement specializations for the different traits options: here I prefer wrapping the function inside a functor class because you can use partial specialization on it, while it's not possible with template functions (you only have overloading and I, personnaly, find partial specialization easier to manipulate)
5. wrap the functor call inside a simple function call to take advantage of template argument deduction

[EDIT] answer and codes snippet based on initial version of the question

[EDIT] C++17 version

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

// in general, a MatrixType is not a row matrix
template <typename MatrixType>
struct isRowMatrix : public std::false_type {};

// declare your classes
class RowMatrix {};
class ColumnMatrix {};

// now you can specialize the trait

// A RowMatrix, is a row matrix
template <>
struct isRowMatrix<RowMatrix> : public std::true_type {};
// same for column matrix
template <typename MatrixType>
struct isColMatrix : public std::false_type {};
// A RowMatrix, is a row matrix
template <>
struct isColMatrix<ColumnMatrix> : public std::true_type {};

// Just needed to compile the last case below
template <class MatrixOut, class MatrixIn>
void genericCopy(MatrixOut&, const MatrixIn&) {
    std::cout << "generic copy" << std::endl;
}

// wrapping it into a function to keep it user friendly and get use of template
// argument deduction
template <class MatrixOut, class MatrixIn>
void copy(MatrixOut& out, const MatrixIn& in) {
    if constexpr (isColMatrix<MatrixOut>::value &&
                  isColMatrix<MatrixIn>::value) {
        std::cout << "column based copy" << std::endl;
    } else {
        if constexpr (isRowMatrix<MatrixOut>::value &&
                      isRowMatrix<MatrixIn>::value) {
            std::cout << "row based copy" << std::endl;
        } else {
            genericCopy(out, in);
        }
    }
}

int main() {
    RowMatrix Rin, Rout;
    ColumnMatrix Cin, Cout;
    copy(Rout, Rin);
    copy(Cout, Cin);
    return 0;
}
```

[Live Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/7Pf71ncG1)

[EDIT] bonus: SFINAE version (also C++14 compliant)

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

// in general, a MatrixType is not a row matrix
template <typename MatrixType>
struct isRowMatrix : public std::false_type {};

// declare your classes
class RowMatrix {};
class ColumnMatrix {};

// now you can specialize the trait

// A RowMatrix, is a row matrix
template <>
struct isRowMatrix<RowMatrix> : public std::true_type {};
// same for column matrix
template <typename MatrixType>
struct isColMatrix : public std::false_type {};
// A RowMatrix, is a row matrix
template <>
struct isColMatrix<ColumnMatrix> : public std::true_type {};

// just needed to compile the last case below
template <class MatrixOut, class MatrixIn>
void genericCopy(MatrixOut&, const MatrixIn&) {
    std::cout << "generic copy" << std::endl;
}

// Using SFINAE in order to select an overload

// this overload is well formed only of both input are row matrices (otherwise
// enable_if_t does not exist)
template <class MatrixOut, class MatrixIn,
          std::enable_if_t<isRowMatrix<MatrixOut>::value &&
                               isRowMatrix<MatrixIn>::value,
                           bool> = true>
void copy(MatrixOut& out, const MatrixIn& in) {
    std::cout << "row based copy" << std::endl;
}

// this overload is well formed only of both input are col matrices (otherwise
// enable_if_t does not exist)
template <class MatrixOut, class MatrixIn,
          std::enable_if_t<isColMatrix<MatrixOut>::value &&
                               isColMatrix<MatrixIn>::value,
                           bool> = true>
void copy(MatrixOut& out, const MatrixIn& in) {
    std::cout << "column based copy" << std::endl;
}

// this overload is well formed only in the other cases (otherwise
// enable_if_t does not exist)
template <
    class MatrixOut, class MatrixIn,
    std::enable_if_t<
        (!(isColMatrix<MatrixOut>::value && isColMatrix<MatrixIn>::value)) &&
            (!(isRowMatrix<MatrixOut>::value && isRowMatrix<MatrixIn>::value)),
        bool> = true>
void copy(MatrixOut& out, const MatrixIn& in) {
    genericCopy(out, in);
}

int main() {
    RowMatrix Rin, Rout;
    ColumnMatrix Cin, Cout;
    copy(Rout, Rin);
    copy(Cout, Cin);
    return 0;
}
```

[Live Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/99bnhPo4M)

In this version, instead of function wrapping a functor that I specialize partially, I write 3 overloads of the copy function using [SFINAE](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/sfinae): only one overload is valid for each situation, the ill-formed ones do not trigger an error. You can also check [this post](https://www.foonathan.net/2015/11/overload-resolution-4/)

Comment: The demo does not have getRowSlice () / getColumnSlice () which differentiates RowMatrix / ColumnMatrix and is the root the problem.  That said, I will try the partial specialized class approach you showed here.  Thanks!

Comment: By the way, if you use C++17, you may simplify a lot my example by using if constexpr instead of the partial specializations of Copier

Comment: Unfortunately, cannot use C++17 :(  At most C++14.

Comment: @user1456982 only the last example is C++17 (if constexpr). The [previous one](https://godbolt.org/z/sErj4rMM9) is valid for C++14.

Comment: @user1456982 it's not the last example anymore as I added the SFINAE version (which is also C++14 compliant).

Answer (score 1):

Your trait doesn't add any information. You can use the type itself:

```
template<class MatrixOut, class MatrixIn>
void
copy (MatrixOut& out, const MatrixIn& in)
{
    if constexpr (std::is_same_v<MatrixOut, MatrixIn>)
    {
        vectorCopy (out, in);
    }
    else
    {
        generalCopy (out, in);
    }
}
```

If your specialised copy functions need to be different, you can do that too:

```
template<class MatrixOut, class MatrixIn>
void
copy (MatrixOut& out, const MatrixIn& in)
{
    if constexpr (std::is_same_v<ColumnMatrix, MatrixOut> && std::is_same_v<ColumnMatrix, MatrixIn>)
    {
        vectorCopyColumn (out, in);
    }
    else if constexpr (std::is_same_v<RowMatrix, MatrixOut> && std::is_same_v<RowMatrix, MatrixIn>)
    {
        vectorCopyRow (out, in);
    }
    else
    {
        generalCopy (out, in);
    }
}
```

Comment: I am just using getRowSlice / getColumnSlice as an example.  The actual use case cannot have the function renamed and the function signatures will be different.

Comment: @user1456982 So `vectorCopy` isn't one function, but two? Otherwise you can add `getSlice()` and delegate to `getShapeSlice()`